# PHPMailer - How to add more then one EmbeddedImage

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have problem with PHP mailer.

I try to send email with Embedded Image.

The php mailer send only the first image from attachment.

My Code:

Get path to all image in html using simple_html_dom.php

```
foreach($ht->find('img') as $img)
        {
            $val=$img->src;

                $val=explode('/',$val);//
                $count=count($val);//

            $img->src='cid:attach_'.$i;//
            $img->alt=$val[$count-1];//
            $img->width=null;
            $img->height=null;
        //  var_dump($val[$count-1]);
            $attach[$i]['src']='../useruploads/'.$temple->id_user.'/images/'.$val[$count-1];
            $attach[$i]['cid']='attach_'.$i;
            $attach[$i]['alt']=$val[$count-1];

        $i++;
        }
```

And in function to send email I have loop:

```
while($attach[$i]['src'])
            {
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($attach[$i]['src'], $attach[$i]['cid'], $attach[$i]['alt']);
            $i++;

            }
```

I can't find the bug.

Comment: Are there multiple attachments? Have you confirmed that using a `var_dump` of `$attach`?

Comment: yes
it's look like:
array(2) { [0]=>  array(3) { ["src"]=>  string(66) "../useruploads/22/images/52534a9649370f22188b829ca1d026a2_logo.png" ["cid"]=>  string(8) "attach_0" ["alt"]=>  string(41) "52534a9649370f22188b829ca1d026a2_logo.png" } [1]=>  array(3) { ["src"]=>  string(63) "../useruploads/22/images/a9dffb0719e82b68be32bb04a02862f3_1.png" ["cid"]=>  string(8) "attach_1" ["alt"]=>  string(38) "a9dffb0719e82b68be32bb04a02862f3_1.png" } }

Answer (score 0):

You can call directly inside the loop:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($path, $cid, $name, $encoding,$type);
```

Changing the variables $path, $cid, $name, $encoding,$type to it's correspondents values.

But take care with versions of PHPMailer.
At http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods we have a observation for the v5.0.0:
Adds an embedded attachment. This can include images, sounds, and just about any other document. Make sure to set the $type to an image type. For JPEG images use "image/jpeg" and for GIF images use "image/gif". If you use the MsgHTML() method, there is no need to use AddEmbeddedImage() method.
I don't know your version (and actually don't have reputation enough to comment...).

Hope it helps.